# How to get the sum of all active and inactive investment balances using Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I am trying to query "locked_total_balance":

```
   locked_total_balance = Investment.objects.filter(is_active=True).aggregate(
        total_balance=Sum('balance'))
```

and "total_available_balance":

```
    total_available_balance = Investment.objects.filter(is_active=False).aggregate(
        total_balance=Sum('balance'))
```

but its not working.

Here is my **model**

```
class Investment(models.Model):
    PLAN_CHOICES = (
        ("Basic - Daily 2% for 180 Days", "Basic - Daily 2% for 180 Days"),
        ("Premium - Daily 4% for 360 Days", "Premium - Daily 4% for 360 Days"),
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    plan = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices=PLAN_CHOICES, null=True)
    deposit_amount = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True)
    basic_interest = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True)
    premium_interest = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True)
    investment_return = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True)
    withdraw_amount = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    balance = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    locked_balance = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    investment_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, null=True)
    due_date = models.DateTimeField(null=True)


    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.investment_id)
```

Comment: Have you imported `Sum()`?

Comment: I imported Sum()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is where the problem originated:

```
    locked_total_balance = Investment.objects.filter(is_active=True).aggregate(
        total_balance=Sum('balance'))
```

The <s>`total_balance=Sum('balance'))`</s> should be  `locked_total_balance=Sum('balance'))`.

This fixed the issue.

Comment: Yeah, it can be the issue anyway but I haven't seen the template, so I thought you haven't imported sum(), actually I have fear that whether I need to tell or not, since its very normal what I provided as an answer. From next time remember to share all relevant code as well :)

Comment: @SunderamDubey Noted with thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The query seems right, maybe you haven't imported `Sum()` from `django.db.models`.

Try this:

views.py

```
from appname.models import Investment

from django.db.models import Sum


def anyview(request):
    locked_total_balance = Investment.objects.filter(is_active=True).aggregate(
        total_balance=Sum('balance'))
    total_available_balance = Investment.objects.filter(is_active=False).aggregate(
        total_balance=Sum('balance'))
    print('------------------------------------------------------')
    print(locked_total_balance)
    print(total_available_balance)
    print('------------------------------------------------------')

    return HttpResponse('it is response')
```